# Finding the jacobian of a differential system with a piecewise function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling

My system:
$$\frac{\mathrm{dx} }{\mathrm{d} t}=-ax^2+y^2-\gamma z$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{dy} }{\mathrm{d} t}=- h(y)-\beta y $$
$$\frac{\mathrm{dz} }{\mathrm{d} t}=x+h(y)-\beta z $$

where $h$ is the piecewise function

$$h(y)=\alpha(m_1 y+\frac{1}{2}(m_0 - m_1)(|y+1|-|y-1|)).$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} h}{\mathrm{d} y}=\alpha m_1+0.5(m_0-m_1)(\frac{y+1}{|y+1|}-\frac{y-1}{|y-1|})$$, is this right?
Upon solving, I get the Jacobian $J$

$$J=
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-2ax & 2y  & -\gamma \\
0 & \alpha m-\beta & 0 \\
1 & \alpha m & -\beta \end{array} \right) $$

where, I've decided to generalize the Jacobian for all parts of the piecewise linear function by using the relation:

$$
m =
\begin{cases}
m_1, |y|\geq 1 \\
m_0, |y|\leq 1\\
\end{cases}
$$

Is this a right way to go about it?

Q2.The system with values would look like:
$$\frac{\mathrm{dx} }{\mathrm{d} t}=-0.2x^2+y^2-z$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{dy} }{\mathrm{d} t}=- h(y)-0.2 y $$
$$\frac{\mathrm{dz} }{\mathrm{d} t}=x+h(y)-0.2 z $$

with equilibrium points given by:

$$x^*=(0;0.3140;-0.3140); y^*=(0;80/49;-80/49); z^*=(0;1.5699;-1.5699);$$

so,in the end how would I choose the distribution of the y* coordinates to find the equilibrium points?(as it is clearly shown,all equilibrium points are functions of y*).

The only thing I can say for certain(as you guys have pointed out) is that y* cannot equal to 1.
[image: Graph of the piecewise function]

Comment: Note that $m$ for $|y|=1$ is ill-defined. However if you resolve this it should be fine.

Comment: I wonder what Laplace transforms would do here... I generically think of Laplace transforms to treat points of discontinuity for ODEs...

Comment: There is this famous non smooth iteration map based on the Henon map, it is called the Lozi map. I know you are looking at an ODE but it might be interesting to see what tools they use to study that. The right hand side terms of $y$ and $z$ seem a bit similar in what you have in the Lozi map

Comment: The desired values of $y^*$ are given by solving $-h(y^*) - \beta y^* = 0$ for $y^*$. With your chosen parameter values it looks like you'll have three values for $y^*$, none of them with $|y^*| = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the reason you're computing the Jacobian is to classify equilibria. Recall an equilibrium is a point $(x^*,y^*,z^*)$ at which $\frac{dx}{dt}$, $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{dz}{dt}$ are all zero.

If $y^* \ne \pm 1$, then you can evaluate the Jacobian at this equilibrium and compute its eigenvalues and eigenvectors in order to classify the equilibrium and/or determine the local dynamics. Note, the first row of the Jacobian should be $[ -2 a x, 2 y, -\gamma]$, which is slightly different to what you have, but the rest of your expression looks good, including $m$.

Alternatively if $y^* = \pm 1$, then the Jacobian is undefined at the equilibrium. In this case you'll have to do much more work to prove something useful about the local dynamics. However, presumably this case will only arise as a bifurcation.

Comment: But,isn't the derivative of a absolute value function in the usual sense of variables- y'= x/|x|? So,the jacobian I derived on top should include the derivatives of the absolute values,right? Please note that the only place absolute values occur is in the piecewise function h(y). I'm not really sure if they cancel out.$$\frac{\mathrm{d} h}{\mathrm{d} y}=\alpha m_1+0.5(m_0-m_1)(\frac{y+1}{|y+1|}-\frac{y-1}{|y-1|})$$